# Windows 11 reports an error "check Internet connection" while Internet is actually OK

Tags: windows, internet, internet-connection, windows-11

After updating my laptop from Windows 10 to Windows 11 I faced with some troubles:

- Some applications stays in offline mode (see the pictures below)
- Running an instalation leads to an error saying that there is no Internet connection
- Microsoft Store doesn't run (it starts, the window is showing up but it is desapearing imediately)

The Internet meanwhile is working perfectly at least in my browser (Chrome)

I have a strong filling that some security protocol(s) are broken and blocks some applications and system core to access their servers via secured protocols while http(s) wirks fine.

What can I do to check?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

#### What can I do to check?

Try completely reinitialising all network states.

Run the following commands in an elevated (run as Adminstrator) `cmd` shell:

- Reset WINSOCK entries to installation defaults (reboot required):

  `netsh winsock reset catalog`
- Reset TCP/IP stack to installation defaults:

  `netsh int ip reset reset.log`
- Reset Firewall to installation defaults:

  `netsh advfirewall reset`
- Flush DNS resolver cache:

  `ipconfig /flushdns`
- Renew DNS client registration and refresh DHCP leases:

  `ipconfig /registerdns`
- Flush routing table (reboot required):

  `route /f`

Answer (score 0):

My problem was actially caused by the [CryptoPro](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE) software, which was installed on my PC way before I shifted to Windows 11.

So this problem is mostly specific for Russian users.

Removing the CryptoPro solved the problem.